# How do I find the lowest common multiple of two numbers?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I know this is a classic interview question, but here is my quick attempt at creating a function which returns the lowest common multiple of two numbers, something I never have to do in my day job:

```
def calc_common_multiplyer(int_low, int_high)
  i = 1
  int_high_res = []

  while true
    int_high_res << int_high * i
    if int_high_res.include?(int_low * i)
      return int_low * i
    end 
    i = i+1
  end
end
```

I feel that this is very clunky. Is there a more efficient or standard solution?

Comment: Is this how you would solve this problem on paper?

Comment: I gave myself a limit of 4 minutes to come up with an answer to this question, probably twice the time it should take & that is what I created. Would probably of done the same on paper.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd do this in Ruby:

```
x.lcm(y)
```

:)

Comment: @Mark Thomas, why not add a link and sample showing how it works?

Comment: @theTinMan I usually do, but I was short on time.

Answer (score 3):

First calculate the greatest common divisor (for example with the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)), then

```
lcm(a,b) = if a == 0 && b == 0 then return 0 else return (a*b)/gcd(a,b)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 def find_lcm(n,m)
  n, m = m, n if m < n
  count = m
 until count % n == 0
  count += m 
 end
 count
 end
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!